# Highcharts and pattern-fill

Tags: image, highcharts

i'm trying to build something like this: http://www.u-wert.net/berechnung/u-wert-rechner/?&d0=20&mid0=10&d1=10&mid1=15&d2=5&mid2=70&bt=0&T_i=20&RH_i=50&T_e=-10&RH_e=80&outside=0

Depending on several input forms a highcharts-chart should show the structure of a wall. Therefore I'm using PlotBands and the Highcharts pattern-fill-plugin. Here is the current code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart_panel',
                    type: 'spline',
                    title: { text: 'Text' }
                    }
            });

        var url = '{% url "create_output" %}';
        $('#myForm').change(function() { 
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), 
                type: $(this).attr('method'), 
                url: url, 
                success: function(data) { 

                    if (chart) chart.destroy();

                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'chart_panel',
                            type: 'line'
                            },
                        title: {text: 'Titletext'},
                        xAxis: {title: {text: "x-Axis text"}},
                        yAxis: {title: {text: "yAxis text"}},
                    });


                    // Adds a series  
                    chart.addSeries({                        
                        name: "Series name",
                        data: data["seriesdata"]
                        });



                    // Plots the wall layer

                    $.each(data["thickness_from"], function(index, value ) {

                        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                            from: value,
                            to: data["thickness_to"][index],
                            color: {pattern: data["image"][index], 
                                    width: data["width"][index],
                                    height: data["height"][index]
                                    },
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Most of the things working pretty well and Highcharts doing a good job plotting "normal patterns". But problems occur when plotting other than normal patterns more than once. For instance when plotting insulation wall layers (similar to waves) which should fit exactly into the given widths. Highcharts then displays the patterns as one connected pattern and the patterns didn't match into the desired widths of the wall layers.

Here is my Question:
Is it possible to set a fixed starting point for each wall-layer-pattern, so that each PlotBand is displayed seperately? Or is an other solution (with renderer.image ?) more suitable for this problem?

Thanks for your reply in advance! :)

Comment: I think you might gain some interest in this by setting up a JFiddle example.

Comment: Maybe better is using an image as pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/VmxPQ/

Comment: Here comes the JFiddle example using the pattern-fill-plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/h6Twd/

Comment: Thanks to Sebastian for the image-as-pattern-example. I tried to use this in an own example with plotbands, but it currently didnt work. (http://jsfiddle.net/A8gQU/1/) Any further ideas or hints?